# How do I return the correct day of the week using dateFormatter in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, date, dateformatter

The following Swift 4 code returns the incorrect day of the week for some cities.

```
// should be "Thu" but returns "Wed" for Aleppo for example
// current location set to Cupertino
// US Cities are correct
let date = "2021-04-29T07:00:00+03:00" // Aleppo
//let date = "2021-04-29T07:00:00-07:00" // Cupertino
let day = self.getDayName(stringDate: date)
print(day)

func getDayName(stringDate: String) -> String
{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: stringDate)!

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E"

    let day = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

    return day
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: "for some cities", could you explain that so we also understand? Also the second part of the format is wrong, it should be a : instead of a - after minutes `hh:mm:ssZ`

Comment: Works fine for US cities but not for European cities for example. This date works fine - 2021-05-03T07:00:00-07:00 but not this - 2021-04-29T07:00:00+03:00. I'm guessing it's a time zone issue but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: A concrete example would be helpful: With input, actual output, expected output, plus locale and time zone information.

Comment: I can’t reproduce this, can you give a clear example

Comment: What time zone do you want?